# MySQL Join performance is really slow

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I am trying to compare values against same table which has more than 1,000,000 rows. Below is my query and it takes around 25 secs to get results.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT a.studyid,a.number,a.load_number,b.studyid,b.number,b.load_number FROM
(SELECT t1.*, buildnumber,platformid FROM t t1
INNER JOIN testlog t2 ON t1.`testid` = t2.`testid`
WHERE (buildnumber =1031719 AND platformid IN (SELECT platformid FROM platform WHERE platform.`Description` = "Windows 7 SP1"))
)AS a
JOIN
(SELECT t1.*,buildnumber,platformid FROM t t1
INNER JOIN testlog t2 ON t1.`testid` = t2.`testid`
WHERE (buildnumber =1030716 AND platformid IN (SELECT platformid FROM platform WHERE platform.`Description` = "Windows 7 SP1"))
)AS b
ON a.studyid=b.studyid AND a.load_number = b.load_number AND a.number = b.number
```

[image]

[image]

Could you anyone help me to improve this query to get fast enough results?
The problem here is even I have number and load_number index, the query doesn't use that. I dont know why it is always ignored..

Thanks.

Comment: 1) It seems you don't need two sub queries. Just join all tables together. 2) don't use IN () which can be very slow with MySQL. Use join instead. 3) Don't use * in sub-queries.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have used the join for all tables but it makes worse..Are you able to play with this table if I send you by email?

Comment: Your `select` is ridiculous.  You are selecting six columns, but there are only three values, based on the `on` clause.

Comment: You can try the answers first. If the problem stays, let us know.

Comment: Yes, the problem is still there.. I cannot figure it out ..

Comment: You can pack few hundreds of your records each table and do a sqlfiddle, including all your table definition, so people can help you to find the direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a silly query.  You are retrieving six columns, but there are only three values.  Look at the `on` clause.

I think your best bet is to rewrite the query using conditional aggregation.  I think the following is equivalent:

```
SELECT t1.studyid, t1.load_number, t1.number
FROM t t1 INNER JOIN
     testlog t2
     ON t1.testid = t2.testid
WHERE t2.buildnumber IN (1031719, 1030716) AND
      platformid IN (SELECT platformid FROM platform p WHERE p.Description = 'Windows 7 SP1'))
GROUP BY studyid, load_number, number
HAVING MIN(buildnumber) <> MAX(buildnumber)
```

For this query, you want indexes on `platform(Description, platformid)` and `testlog(buildnumber, platformid)` and `t(testid)`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, what I am trying to do actually retrieve all values for build number 1031719 from "t" table and also retrieve all values for another build number 1030716 then compare between values. Because all values are different based on different build number.

Comment: SELECT  a.studyid,a.number,a.ACCELERATION,a.APPLIED_FORCE,a.INTERNAL_FORCE,a.MPC_FORCE,a.SPC_FORCE,a.TRANSLATION,a.VELOCITY,a.load_number,b.studyid,b.number,b.ACCELERATION,b.APPLIED_FORCE,b.INTERNAL_FORCE,b.MPC_FORCE,b.SPC_FORCE,b.TRANSLATION,b.VELOCITY,b.load_number      

This is the full select part..

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1:
`IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes *very* poorly.  The subquery is rerun again and again.  It looks like you are expecting exactly one id from that query; if so, change it to `= ( SELECT ... )`.  That way it will be run exactly once.

Problem #2:

```
FROM ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
```

optimizes poorly because neither subquery.  Can you merge the two subqueries into one, as Gordon was trying?  If not, then put one of them into a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and add an appropriate index to that table so that the `ON` will be able to use it.  Probably `PRIMARY KEY(studyid, load_number, number)`.

Footnote:  The latest versions of MySQL have made improvements on these problems by dynamically generating indexes.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am wondering that once I create a temporary table then do I need to join a table with temp table? or how to apply temp table with Select statement? could you please a bit explain more to me?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xx (PRIMARY KEY...) SELECT ...`; Then...  `SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT ..the other subquery...) JOIN xx on .. 3 fields.. Etc`;